# How to avoid redundant traffic in Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, multipart

I have Spring-Boot 2.x application, and some rest controller endpoint that uploads multipart file, like this

```
    @PostMapping("/somePath")
    public ResponseEntity someController(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) )
```

also we have jwtFilter in security filter chain, that checks jwt token for validity;
and we have a situation when **token is not valid, but tomcat consumes traffic**

**how can I check this?**:
  I use spring boot actuator and make request:
   GET  http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/tomcat.global.received

It possible abort traffic until filter checked token?
Is there a way to avoid redundant traffic?

I tried HttpServletRequest and InputStream as controller param, but result is the same.

Comment: I don't know if I actually understood what your problem is. So you want that tomcat doesnt get the request when the token is invalid? Tomcat as the webserver takes the request first of course and gives it to the spring application for further processing. At that point the whole message gets passed to Spring and Spring does the necessary authentication filter checks to figure out if this request should be past to the controllers.

Comment: I want that tomcat doesn't get whole multipart file until the request passes authentication.

Comment: It can be very critical for mobile clients that use 3G/4G internet connection.

Comment: but if the file size like 2Gb and more - it some additional load for application too.

Comment: Then do a call first without the file to check authentication status then the second call with the payload.

Comment: How can I test it?   
Unfortunately, Postman   doesn't support chunked requests https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3684

Comment: @dur I found out that client sends request without Transfer-Encoding : chunked, but how can its help me?

Comment: @dur I tested it  with some http clients with transfer-encoding=chunked and result is the same - client sends all the file even token is expired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given how expensive the file uploads are and not having any better solution, I would in the meantime:

- Determine the extension of time needed to be added on top of the
  token expiry
- Have the client to make a call to validate token before expensive uploads and renew the token as needed
- Having the server, when token is expired to allow for the extension of time during which the expired token would be still considered valid

The other option would be for the client to renew the token before expensive uploads. The client could look at the size of the uploads to make a determination whether to renew or not.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible, the only way - use another balancer application for security reasons. And it is right also if you are thinking about microservices.
Also, it is correct for Separation of concerns.

If you would like to change security logic you should change only the security application.

See [spring-cloud, zuul](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html) for more details.